# Limit rows with Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that looks right. I can see all my rows ordered correctly like this:

```
df1.orderBy($"count".desc)
df1.show()
```

But when I try and add a limit like this:

```
df1.orderBy($"count".desc).limit(5)
df1.show()
```

I'm still getting all the rows. I think I'm following the docs correctly... [https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#limit(n:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#limit(n:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D)

So how do I limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset methods return a new dataset object, they don't mutate the existing one.  So you need to show the result:

```
df2 = df1.orderBy($"count".desc).limit(5)
df2.show()
```